# Onclick function not working inside custom legend chart vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I created custom legends into my charts following this git issue:

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2565

When I try to use `onclick` function inside the custom `legendCallback`, I get an error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: updateChart is not defined at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick".

```js
legendCallback: (chart) => {
        const legendHtml = [];
        legendHtml.push('<table>');
        legendHtml.push('<tr>');
        for (let i=0; i<chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
            const color    = chart.data.datasets[i].borderColor;
            const legendId = 'linear-d'+i;
            legendHtml.push(
                '<td onclick="this.updateDataset(event,' + '\'' + chart.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex + '\'' + ', ' + '\'' + legendId + '\'' + ')">' +
                '<div id="'+legendId+'-square" style="background-color:' + color +'; border: 2px solid ' + color +'; width: 15px; height: 15px;"></div>' +
                '</td>'
            );
            if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
                legendHtml.push('<td id="'+legendId+'-text" style="cursor: default; font-size: 12px;" onclick="this.updateDataset(event,' + '\'' + chart.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex + '\'' + ', ' + '\'' + legendId + '\'' + ')">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label + '</td>');
            }
        }
        legendHtml.push('</tr>');
        legendHtml.push('</table>');
        return legendHtml.join("");
    },
```

I also tried to add `addEventListener` with `.forEach` for every table data, but  then I can't access the chart data from outside the `legendCallback` function.

How can I call the function `updateDataset()` with `onclick` function?

Comment: Have you tried just making the `onclick` do a simple thing, just to make sure it works: `onclick="alert('works!')"`?

Comment: Also, are you getting any error messages when you click?

Comment: Yes, i get the error: "(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: updateChart is not defined at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick"

Comment: Where is `updateChart` coming from. It's not in the code you shared

Comment: If i try to use legendHtml.push('<td onclick="alert("works!")"></td>'
It gives me error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Sorry i changed the name from updateDataset() to updateChart()

Comment: @George did you managed to solve it?

Comment: The onclick inside <td> didn't work, so i had to attach an evenlistener on <td>

 document.querySelectorAll('#legend_table td')
      .forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var meta = legendChart.getDatasetMeta(this.cellIndex)
        meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !legendChart.data.datasets[this.cellIndex].hidden : null
        legendChart.update()
      }))
    }

Comment: can share the complete code ?